# Regarding a number theory proof

Tags: number-theory, integers

Before I begin I should mention that I have only recently started studying number theory.

It is required to prove that there are no positive integers  $a,b,n>1$ such that

$$a^n - b^n\mid a^n+b^n$$

that is $k$ can never be an integer if

$$\frac{a^n+b^n}{a^n-b^n} = k$$

Now if $b|a$ then we can write

$$\frac{(a/b)^n+1}{(a/b)^n-1} = k$$

which is clearly not true for all $a/b$. However I have no idea how to prove the general result. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are $a,b$ real numbers or natural numbers?

Comment: What if $n=2$ and $a=\sqrt3$ and $b=\sqrt 2$

Comment: @HEIFETZ I think the statement is not true if $a,b$ are real numbers. For example, as given above, $(\sqrt (m+1))^2 - (\sqrt m)^2 = 1$, which is a divisor of $(\sqrt (m+1))^2 + (\sqrt (m))^2 = 2m+1$ for all values of $m$.

Comment: I have corrected the mistake. a b and n are all positive integers greater than 1.

Comment: Ok. In that case, there is an answer.

Comment: No, you haven't corrected the mistake. On line two it still talks about *real* numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $\gcd(a,b)=d$, $a=da_1$ and $b=db_1$, then $\gcd(a_1,b_1)=1$. We proceed by proof by contradiction. If $a^n-b^n\mid a^n+b^n$, then $a_1^n-b_1^n\mid a_1^n+b_1^n$, so $a_1^n-b_1^n\mid2a_1^n$ and $a_1^n-b_1^n\mid2b_1^n$, leading to $a_1^n-b_1^n\mid\gcd(2a_1^n,2b_1^n)=2$. Hence $a_1^n-b_1^n\mid2$.

Without loss of generality we assume $a>b$, and so $a_1>b_1$. Since $a_1^n-b_1^n\mid2$ we have $a_1^n-b_1^n=1$ or $2$, but $$a_1^n-b_1^n=(a_1-b_1)(a_1^{n-1}b_1+a_1^{n-2}b_1^2+\cdots+a_1b_1^{n-1})>n\geq2,$$ which is a contradiction!

Answer (score 0):

Notice if $a^n - b^n|a^n + b^n$ then $a^n - b^n|a^n + b^n + a^n - b^n = 2a^n$ and $a^n - b^n| a^n + b^n -(a^n- b^n) = 2b^n$.

So if $p|a^n - b^n$ and $p$ is prime either $p = 2$ or $p|a$ and $p|b$.

Let $d = \gcd (a,b)$ and let $a = a'd; b = b'd$ then $\frac{a^n - b^n}{a^n + b^n}= \frac {a'^n - b'^n}{a'^n + b'^n}$ and $a^n - b^n| a^n + b^n \iff a'^n - b'^n|a'^n + b'^n$.

So $a'^n - b'^n|2a'^n$ and $a'^n- b'^n|2b'^n$ and for any prime $p \ne 2$ if $p|a'^n - b'^n$ then $p|a'$ and $p|b'$ so $p|\gcd(a'b') =1$ which is impossible.  So no prime other than $2$ divides $a'^n - b'^n$.

So $a'^n - b'^n = 2^m$.  But only $2$ can't divide both $a'$ and $b'$ so $a'^n - b'^n = 2$ or $a'^n - b'^n = 1$.

So $(a'^n - b'^n) = (a'-b')(a'^{n-1}+ a'^{n-2}b'+ ... + a'b'^{n-2} + b'^{n-1})$.

Clearly $a'-b' < (a'^{n-1}+ a'^{n-2}b'+ ... + a'b'^{n-2} + b'^{n-1})$ and $(a'^{n-1}+ a'^{n-2}b'+ ... + a'b'^{n-2} + b'^{n-1}) > 0$ so

$a -b = 1$ and $(a'^{n-1}+ a'^{n-2}b'+ ... + a'b'^{n-2} + b'^{n-1})= 2$

$(a'^{n-1}+ a'^{n-2}b'+ ... + a'b'^{n-2} + b'^{n-1}) = 2$ is only possible if $n= 1$.  And indeed if $a-b =1$ then $1|a+b$ but... $n$ must be bigger than $1$ and that is impossible.